# NAS on Router not accessible from Wifi Repeater SSID

Tags: wireless-networking, router, nas

**Background**:

I have a wifi router with USB memory attached, serving as both router (SSID: PLUS) and NAS.
I also have a wifi extender (SSID: NEXX).

**Problem**:

I can access my NAS only when connected to SSID:PLUS.
If I connect to the SSID:NEXX, I can no longer access the NAS.

**Solution**:
I solved this myself so add the solution now...

When connected to the NEXX wifi repeater SSID, I noticed I could ping the PLUS router.  So I realised the problem was related to login credentials.

When you are on the PLUS SSID, it doesnt seem to need login to access the USB.

But when you are on the NEXX wifi repeater SSID, it needs login.  And I was not being given any prompt to input username/password.  So the solution is to provide username/pass when trying to access the USB.

On windows device, open credentials manager and create a new windows credential for the PLUS router ip (e.g. 192.168.1.254) with the admin username/password.  I could then connect to the USB from Windows Explorer using 192.168.1.254/usb1 as the path

On Android Device, you can probably connect via a file manager app.  I was using Kodi, as I wanted to watch videos on the NAS usb, so I was able to set up a connection from Kodi via Video -> Add Videos -> Browse -> Add Network Connection -> Windows Fileshare NFS -> then input the IP, directory and login to connect.

It works great, the speed is fast enough to stream 1080p from the PLUS router to kodi on the android device on the wifi extender ssid.

Comment: use wifi extender NEXX in bridge mode.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont think it has bridge mode?  The manual says 'AP mode' and 'Repeater mode' only.  I can put OpenWRT on it as a last resort.  https://fccid.io/document.php?id=2241507

Comment: they call it _wifi repeater_

Comment: the nexx is in wifi repeater mode already.

Comment: it should be use the same subnet as PLUS (in bridge mode). Openwrt could be a solution, it can do bridging.

Comment: Just realised my question is wrong.  The USB NAS is on the parent router not the NEXX.  But the problem is the same, I can only access the NAS when connected to the PLUS SSID.  From the NEXX SSID I cannot access the NAS.  Will putting openwrt and bridge mode on the Nexx device allow the Pc connected to SSID:NEXX to access the NAS on PLUS?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. Are you able to ping the PLUS router when connected via NEXX SSID? I'm not an expert on repeater mode, but to me the NEXX router shouldn't have his own subnet at all.

Comment: What repeater do you use?